# If we find that, e.g., T(n)<=d*n*lg(n) for some d that depends on n, is T(n)=o(nlgn)?

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis

In the substitution method, if we find that, for instance, T(n) < d*n*lg(n) but only for some d that depends on n, then can we say that T(n) = o(nlg(n)) (little-oh) in some cases? For example, in this case: we may find that the condition T(n) <= d*n*lg(n) is only satisfied if d <= n or, conversely, n>=d. That would mean that, for every d, we can find an n0 such that T(n) < d*n*lg(n) as long as n>=n0=d, which is the condition for o(nlgn). I am not sure if this line of reasoning is correct.

Comment: I think this might be more useful if you focused on your actual situation, rather than asking whether something could be true in some cases.

Comment: Sorry, there is no actual situation! It's hypothetical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Suppose $d=1/n$ and $T(n) = 0.5 \log n$.  Then you'll find that $T(n) < d n \log n$, and it is also true that $T(n) = o(n \log n)$.

In this case, it might be misleading to use a letter like $d$ for a function of $n$; people might expect you to write $d(n)$.  Typically, letters like $c,d,\dots$ are used for constants (which don't depend on $n$).

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is wrong. In the first place, unless $d(n)$ is constant, $n\ge n_0=d$ does not hold. And even if that was the case, $dn\log(n)=o(n\log(n))$ would be incorrect (as is the statement "for every $d$").

Clearly

$$d(n)n\log(n)=o(n\log(n))$$ requires

$$d(n)=o(1).$$

---

Last but not least,

$$T(n)\le d(n)n\log(n)$$ is the very condition for

$$T(n)=O(d(n)n\log(n))$$ whatever the function $d(n)$.